# Java: Open xml-File inside a Jar. Not able to open it

Tags: java, xml, file, jar

I want to Read a XML-Document which is inside my .jar-File

When i export into jar (Via Intelliji), the Programm cant find my File (java.io.FileNotFoundException). I tried everything (Jar-Path, Classloader etc.) I also Export this file in the Jar. First the file is in the Project Directory But cant open it, until i extract it....

This is the Position in the Project Directory:

`inputFile =  new File("SommersemesterStundenobjekte.xml");`

Also when i give the right Path inside to the jar. Not able to open it:

> inputFile = new File(getJarPath() + "\SommersemesterStundenobjekte.xml ");

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\StundeplanRaunig1.0.3.jar\SommersemesterStundenobjekte.xml  (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)

But i want, that the Programm works only with the jar-File.

Please Help :)

Comment: When that file is inside the jar, it is not a ``File`` but a resource. Try ``getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename)``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `File` in this case. Use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/SommersemesterStundenobjekte.xml")`